# Removing extraneous divs in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using the header "global text-area" inside a view within drupal7. For some reason when I use the header function in the view I get a bunch of extraneous divs like the following at the end of my header:

```
 </div></div></div>    </div>
```

How do I remove these? If I remove the header (which I need or at least an alternative they go away. I am using semantic views in case in you are wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Views will automatically close any opened divs in the header. Double-check your text format. Are you using any kind of WYSIWYG editor in the text area? Have you opened any divs yourself?

Try the following:

- Switch the text area format to "Plain text" and see if the extra closing divs disappear.
- Read the page source of the rendered View, and check if the extra closing divs correspond with any opening divs. If so, note the classes and/or content of the opening divs, and see if it tips you on which module has generated them.
- If you've not opened any manual divs in the header, try wrapping the header in a div (Full HTML format) and see if it influences the result.

If none of these works, please supply more details and I'll take another shot at it.